# ARKit – Rendering a 3D object under an invisible plane

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an ARKit scene with an invisible `SCNPlane`:

```
plane.geometry?.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
```

This plane is placed on the ground and is used to render `deferred shadows` from other objects placed in the scene.

I want to render another `SCNPlane` which should be on the same level as the invisible plane (same `Z`-coordinate). The problem is, that every time the new object is under the invisible plane, it is not rendered at all.

Is there any way to render the object when it is under the invisible plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can achieve it using the following lines of code:

```
shadowsPlane.geometry?.materials.first?.writesToDepthBuffer = true
shadowsPlane.geometry?.materials.first?.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
```

Choose one of two instance properties for **`.colorBufferWriteMask`**:

```
shadowsPlane.geometry?.materials.first?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
```

Set a rendering order for your objects like:

```
shadowsPlane.renderingOrder = -1   // the nearest layer
```

And, of course, use an appropriate **`.lightingModel`** instance property:

```
shadowsPlane.geometry?.materials.first?.lightingModel = .constant
```

Remember, there will be some tiny air gap between two planes:

```
shadowsPlane.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
floorPlane.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -0.01, z: 0)
```

Comment: I was almost there. Rendering order + .alpha did the trick. I had to set -1 for the farthest layer (the object under the invisible plane) and 100 for the invisible plane itself. It works great now.